# PyQt5 Qthread attribut error, calling self.somelist

Tags: python, pyqt5, qthread

I have several thread. and very long main script.

I tried several solution from others but no result.

I understand attrubution error is very basic thing

in my main

```
@pyqtSlot()
def save_usermade(self):
    user_id = self.lineEdit_4.text().strip()
    input5 = [user_id, and some more strings...]
    self.WorkerD_1 = Worker4_1()
    self.sig_1.connect(self.WorkerD_1.save_ad)
    self.WorkerD_1.start()
    self.sig_1.emit(input5)
    self.WorkerD_1.sig4_1_1.connect(self.append_table)
```

in my thread

```
class Worker4_1(QThread):
    sig4_1_1 = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def save_ad(self, listD_1):
        self.adlist = listD_1        

    def run(self):
        print(self.adlit)
        userID = self.adlist[0]
        and some works to do...
```

I got error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\codes\MYPROJECT\Basic\Thread_w4_1.py", line 34, in run
    print(self.adlist)
AttributeError: 'Worker4_1' object has no attribute 'adlist'
```

anyone know why?

would it be because I did `self.sig_1.emit(input5)` after `self.Worferd_1.start()`?

---

I changed oder `self.sig_1.emit(input5)` first than `self.Worferd_1.start()` after.
it seems work fine. any one know why?

Comment: mmm, it seems that you don't know the SO rules, I recommend you check [ask] and check the [tour]. In SO you should not add SOLVED to the question title but: 1) If you have obtained the answer then publish it and mark it as correct tomorrow, OR 2) if the published answers have solved your problem then you must mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Worker4_1(QThread):
    sig4_1_1 = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self,adList, parent=None):#edited here
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.adList = adList


    def run(self):
        print(self.adlit)
        userID = self.adlist[0]
        and some works to do...
```

and on main:

```
@pyqtSlot()
def save_usermade(self):
    user_id = self.lineEdit_4.text().strip()
    input5 = [user_id, and some more strings...]
    self.WorkerD_1 = Worker4_1(adList = input5)
```

Comment: do you mean my_list_in_here by input5?

Comment: y you need to pass the list via the constructor (in init)

Comment: thanks alot!!!!!! you sloved it. do you know any doc that I can see why there is different between your's and mine?

Comment: There are many examples on how to use pyqt5 threads and signals, but I think you must read on how classes and inheritance works generally in python(inheritance , parents etc) .You can find online anything.If this answer solved your problem mark it as answered,Good luck!